# Having individual items appear selected when ListView.setChoiceMode is set to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

When you use the ADT with Eclipse, and tell the ADT to create a new activity with a Master/Detail Flow, this method will appear in one of the fragments:

```
/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}
```

However, I want to implement a `MultiChoiceModeListener`. Thus, that requires me to eliminate all references to this method, as it would remove the `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` that is required. However, I still want individual items to appear as 'activated' after selecting one of them from the list when the `ActionMode` isn't active, since I am still displaying that item's details. (Obviously, switching when appropriate) Is there a way to go about do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I still want individual items to appear as 'activated' after
>   selecting one of them from the list when the ActionMode isn't active,
>   since I am still displaying that item's details. (Obviously, switching
>   when appropriate) Is there a way to go about do that?

First of all, what you want to do seems a bit counter intuitive. You'll have a row activated when the contextual action bar isn't shown but you'll allow the user to select multiple rows(?!) when the CAB is present(what will happen with the details panel when the CAB is present and the user selects various rows?!). What will happen when the CAB is dismissed with multiple rows being selected(activated)? What will happen with the details panel when the CAB is dismissed?

Anyway, probably the easiest way to do what you want would be to keep the generated method(along with the choice mode) and lose the `MultiChoiceListener`. Instead you'll be managing your own `ActionMode` for the `ListView` simulating the `MultiChoiceModeListener`. That `ActionMode` will be triggered from a `OnItemLongClickListener` on the `ListView`.

Comment: I came here looking for the same use case as the OP: I wanted to have both CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE and CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL. I agree that it seems a bit ... strange .. but there are use cases for this. The GMail app and Play Store client both have similar functionality in dual-pane mode(although GMail uses check boxes to make things a little less strange). IMO, it is not all that rare for this requirement to come up.